# Retrieving data from 6pm previous day till 6pm present day

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table with column "create_date". I want to select records which are inserted after 6 pm previous day till 6pm present day.This data is to be fetched everyday w/o need to manually enter date and time.
So can anyone help me to write a query to fetch records which falls under this criteria.
Column data type is Date.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just your condition with `TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) + 18/24`

Comment: Thanks a lot. can you please tell for condition "present day's 6 pm"

Comment: `trunc(sysdate-1) + 18/24` for previous day, and `trunc(sysdate) + 18/24` for present day. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For previous day 6PM, you could use `TRUNC(SYSDATE -1)`, which will trunc the time portion to `00:00:00` and then add 18 hours. Similarly, for present day ,do `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` and add 18 hours.

```
SQL> SELECT to_char(trunc(SYSDATE -1) + 18/24,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  2  FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDA
-------------------
02/25/2015 18:00:00

SQL>
```

So, **trunc(SYSDATE -1) + 18/24** gives you yesterday's date as 6PM.

**Test case:**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT 'text' col, SYSDATE create_date FROM dual
  3    )
  4  SELECT *
  5  FROM DATA
  6  WHERE create_date
  7  BETWEEN (TRUNC(sysdate -1) + 18/24) AND (TRUNC(sysdate) + 18/24)
  8  /

COL  CREATE_DA
---- ---------
text 26-FEB-15

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want desired result then first you have to change your column's datatype into `Timestamp.` Then store values with time into that column. And then
Try this:-

```
SELECT *
FROM TAB_NAME
WHERE EXTRACT (HOUR FROM create_date) >= 6
AND EXTRACT (DATE FROM create_date) = SYSDATE - 1
```

Comment: Why `TIMESTAMP`? A `DATE` has both datetime elements. Timestamp is an extenstion to the date data type. I don't see a reason to use timestamp here. See my answer.

Comment: I just wanted to say that if the user wants to extract hour from date, time part must be present there. Thats why i was recommending timestamp.

Comment: You can still use extract, you just need to cast date as timestamp.