# Define logic to calculate day from 02:00:00 AM till 02:00:00 AM

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following sql query get sum of total hours for whole day,
this query works ok except the day for our objects starts from 02:00:00 AM till 02:00:00 AM of following day and in this query it groups daytime by normal day hours 12:00:00 AM till 12:59:59 PM.
How to add logic to group daytime from 02:00:00 AM till 02:00:00 AM?

```
    select object_code, 
    sum(on_stream_hrs) on_stream_hrs,
    daytime 
from(select object_code, 
            on_stream_hrs, 
            trunc(daytime) daytime 
     from sub_day_status 
     where trunc(daytime) between to_date('1 Feb 2017') and to_date('28 Feb 2017')
     ) 
where (object_code, daytime) in (select object_code, 
                                    trunc(daytime) 
                                 from  sub_day_status 
                                 where trunc(daytime) between to_date('1 Feb 2017') and to_date('28 Feb 2017') 
                                 and on_stream_hrs >0.5)
group by object_code, daytime 
order by daytime
```

thanks,
S

Comment: I guess you could shift the timezone by two hours.

Comment: I found something similar but not sure I can apply it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736490/retrieving-data-from-6pm-previous-day-till-6pm-present-day?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just subtract 2 hours from the `daytime` before truncating:

```
SELECT object_code, 
       SUM( on_stream_hrs ) AS on_stream_hrs,
       TRUNC( daytime - INTERVAL '2' HOUR ) AS daytime
FROM   sub_day_status
WHERE  daytime >= DATE '2017-02-01' + INTERVAL '2' HOUR
AND    daytime <  DATE '2017-03-01' + INTERVAL '2' HOUR
GROUP BY
       object_code, 
       TRUNC( daytime - INTERVAL '2' HOUR )
HAVING MAX( on_stream_hrs ) > 0.5
ORDER BY
       daytime;
```

The correlated sub-query appears to be something that you can either use a simple `WHERE on_stream_hrs > 0.5` or by using a `HAVING` clause (as above) depending on how you want to filter the rows.

Comment: to MTO: will do, thanks a lot again, perfect work!!!! all best to you and your family!!

Answer (score 0):

> where trunc(daytime) between to_date('1 Feb 2017') and to_date('28 Feb
>   2017')

you can move the date by 2 hours by the following.

```
select to_date('1 Feb 2018', 'DD MON YYYY') + 2/24 from dual
```

[Reference](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-jan/o12plsql-1408561.html)

Comment: But how I can tell to group daytime by 02:00:00 AM till 02:00:00 AM, so it sums only hours between 02:00:00 AM till 02:00:00 AM?

Comment: no, this doesn't really give me anything, still question, how I can tell to group daytime by 02:00:00 AM till 02:00:00 AM, so it sums only hours between 02:00:00 AM till 02:00:00 AM?